# Ejabberd Authentication

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I have my rails app. And whenever user registers, I want to register user on ejabberd node as well. But, whenever i call register API using curl request, it gives be following error:
`{"status":"error","code":32,"message":"AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation."}`

My curl request is:

`curl -X POST --data '{"user": "bob", "host": "localhost", "password": "password"}' http://localhost:5443/api/register`

My `ejabberd.yml` file is as below:

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"

loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
    web_admin: true
    captcha: true
    tls: false

commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands: [user, admin, open]
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all


s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  admin:
    user:
     - "admin@localhost"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "::1/128"
      - "::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128"

access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  register:
    - allow
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback
  oauth:
    - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
    - allow: admin

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: admin@localhost
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: admin@localhost
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "0.0.0.0"
    what:
      - "register"
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: "https://@HOST@:5443/upload"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    ip: "localhost"
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep"
    force_node_config:
      ## Change from "whitelist" to "open" to enable OMEMO support
      ## See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2425
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: whitelist
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      "storage:bookmarks":
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
  show_os: false
```

Can someone point me where exactly I might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mod_http_api from localhost to register accounts, you can grant it permission in this way:

```
api_permissions:
  "http_api commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    from:
      - mod_http_api
    what:
      - "register"
```

See https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in before requesting this? or r u using any kind of authentication mechanism?
If you r requesting without this try adding the ip from which you are requesting insode

```
"public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "0.0.0.0"
    what:
      - "register"
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
```

**part.**
Else try adding allow all under register in **api_permission** section

Comment: yes adding ip solved the problem.. But I believe if i set ip to 0.0.0.0, it should accept request from all IP addresses. but not sure why it fails and gives me error..

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. You might be requesting from external ip address

Comment: This can cause potential security problems because 0.0.0.0 implies that you're binding on all network interfaces including those that might be exposed to the public internet.